# Inputting into two different tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Having a syntax error when trying the transactions that i found on this site, seems Im doing something wrong here. Please help

```
        if($Output>0)
        {
            //SQL Insert
            $sql = 
            "BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO bird(Name) VALUES ('$_POST[Name]');
            INSERT INTO type(Label) VALUES ('$_POST[Type]');
            COMMIT";
            //Confirmation Msg
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
            {$Confirm=$_POST['Type'].' has been added to our database<br>';}
            else
            {die(mysqli_error($conn));}
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
        else
            {$CheckErr="Username Does Not Exist";}
    }
```

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_query` does not support multi-queries. [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) does.